# Largest subarray with sum equal to 0

Tags: python, algorithm, interview-questions

This is a typical interview question:

> Given an array that contains both positive and negative elements without 0, find the largest subarray whose sum equals 0.

I am not sure if this will satisfy all the edge case. If someone can comment on that, it would be excellent. I also want to extend this to sum equaling to any ,  not just 0. How should I go about it? And any pointers to optimize this further is also helpful.

```
from collections import Counter

def sub_array_sum(array,k=0):
    start_index = -1
    hash_sum = {}
    current_sum = 0
    keys = set()
    best_index_hash = Counter()
    for i in array:
        start_index += 1
        current_sum += i
        if current_sum in hash_sum:
            hash_sum[current_sum].append(start_index)
            keys.add(current_sum)
        else:
            if current_sum == 0:
                best_index_hash[start_index] = [(0,start_index)]
            else:
                hash_sum[current_sum] = [start_index]
    if keys:
        for k_1 in keys:
            best_start = hash_sum.get(k_1)[0]
            best_end_list = hash_sum.get(k_1)[1:]
            for best_end in best_end_list:
                if abs(best_start-best_end) in best_index_hash:
                    best_index_hash[abs(best_start-best_end)].append((best_start+1,best_end))
                else:
                    best_index_hash[abs(best_start-best_end)] = [(best_start+1,best_end)]

    if best_index_hash:
        (bs,be) = best_index_hash[max(best_index_hash.keys(),key=int)].pop()
        print array[bs:be+1]
    else:
        print "No sub array with sum equal to 0"


def Main():
    a = [6,-2,8,5,4,-9,8,-2,1,2]
    b = [-8,8]
    c = [7,8,-1,1]
    d = [2200,300,-6,6,5,-9]
    e = [-9,-6,8,6,-14,9,6]
    sub_array_sum(a)
    sub_array_sum(b)
    sub_array_sum(c)
    sub_array_sum(d)
    sub_array_sum(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Are only subarrays with *contiguous* elements from the original array allowed, or arbitrary elements?

Comment: Yes. Only contiguous elements.

Comment: I think that contiguous subsequences are called *substrings*.

Answer (score 4):

I have to admit I didn't fully understood the algorithm. Anyway it seems suboptimal, due to use of heaviweight containers and a nested loops, and is really hard to follow.

I would rather start with an observation that replacing the array with its partial sums reduces the problem to finding *two equal elements* as distant as possible (two partial sums being equal means the sum in between is 0). This is pretty trivial:

- Calculate partial sums (\$O(n)\$)
- Stable sort `(sum(i),i)` tuples (\$O(n\log^2n\$))
- Scan for largest `equal range` (\$O(n)\$)

Comment: Just to explain why this works.
You create an array with element like 
\$ a'_i = a_0+...+a_i \$ 
So \$ a'_i = a'_{(i+k)} \Rightarrow a_0+...+a_i = a_0+...+a_i + ... +a_{(i+k)} \Rightarrow  0 = a_{(i+1)} + ... + a_{(i+k)}
\$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a linear time solution. The only drawback is that it relies on dictionaries; well, it's still \$O(1)\$ per dictionary operation, but the constant factors are a little bit larger. Also, I would implement a class for representing exactly solutions to the problem:

```
class ZeroSubarray:

    def __init__(self, arr, from_index, to_index):
        self.arr = arr
        self.from_index = from_index
        self.to_index = to_index

    def __str__(self):
        ret = ""
        ret += "from_index=" + str(self.from_index)
        ret += ", to_index=" + str(self.to_index)
        ret += ", subarray=["
        sep = ""

        for i in range(self.from_index, self.to_index):
            ret += sep
            sep = ", "
            ret += str(self.arr[i])

        ret += "]"
        return ret


def zero_subarray_length(arr):
    cumulative_array = [0 for i in range(len(arr) + 1)]

    # This is O(n), where n = len(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(cumulative_array)):
        cumulative_array[i] = cumulative_array[i - 1] + arr[i - 1]

    map = {}

    # This is O(n) as well
    for index in range(len(cumulative_array)):
        current_value = cumulative_array[index]

        if current_value not in map.keys():
            list = [index]
            map[current_value] = list
        else:
            map[current_value].append(index)

    best_distance = 0
    best_start_index = -1

    # O(n) too. Each index into cumulative is stored in a dicttionary
    # and so the size of the dict is O(n):
    for value, list in map.items():
        min_index = list[0]
        max_index = list[-1]
        current_distance = max_index - min_index
        if best_distance < current_distance:
            best_distance = current_distance
            best_start_index = min_index

    return ZeroSubarray(arr, best_start_index, best_start_index + best_distance)

print(zero_subarray_length([2, 3, 6, -1, -4]))
```

Hope that helps.